# Console.log doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's my first steps in learning javascript, and I have simple code:

```
$(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $.get('/', function(data) {
      console.log('Request ' + i + ' succeeded');
    }); }
});
```

but for me it shows only last string: "Request 5 succeeded", why does it show only last one? How can I fix it?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200) for explanation what is a closure in JS and how they work.

Comment: You mean to say it prints `Request 5 succeeded` 5 times?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ekk1ekj0/1/